# In FsCheck.XUnit, how do I get verbose checking?

Tags: f#, xunit, xunit.net, fscheck

How do I get the runs generated when using `[<Property>]` to use the `Check.VerboseAll` style of generation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
[<Property(Verbose = true)>]
let myTestFunction ...
```